# Noether's theorem and EL equations for $\int_a^b L\left(x(t),u(t),\frac{u_t}{x_t},\frac{1}{x_t}\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{u_t}{x_t}\right]\right)x_t\,dt$

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am looking for a faster way to find the appropriate Euler-Lagrange equations for a variational problem of the form
$$\mathcal{L}[x,u] = \int_a^b L\left(x(t),u(t),\frac{u_t}{x_t},\frac{1}{x_t}\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{u_t}{x_t}\right]\right)x_t\,dt$$
obtained by parameterizing the standard second-order Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}[u] = \int_{x_0}^{x_1}L(x,u,u_x,u_{xx})\,dx$ in terms of a dummy variable $t$. Specifically, I would like a faster way of doing this than the approach that you generally take for the computation of the first-order EL equations and first integral formulas. If we consider the first-order case
$$\mathcal{L}[x,u] = \int_a^b L\left(x(t),u(t),\frac{u_t}{x_t}\right)x_t\,dt$$
and define a path $\gamma:(-1,1)\rightarrow G$ with $\gamma(0) = e$ then we may define the group infinitesimals by
$$\left.\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\varepsilon = 0}\gamma(\varepsilon)\cdot x := \theta\qquad \left.\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\varepsilon = 0}\gamma(\varepsilon)\cdot u := \psi\qquad \left.\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\varepsilon = 0}\gamma(\varepsilon)\cdot u_I := \psi_I$$
where $I = xx..x$. Taking the standard approach to finding the EL equations, we can then compute
$$\begin{align*}0&=\int_a^b \left.\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\varepsilon = 0}L\left(\gamma(\varepsilon)\cdot x(t),\gamma(\varepsilon)\cdot u(t),\gamma(\varepsilon)\cdot \frac{u_t}{x_t}\right)\gamma(\varepsilon)\cdot x_t\,dt\\
&=\int_a^b \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} x_t \theta + \frac{\partial L}{\partial u}x_t \psi + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{u_t}{x_t}}\left(\frac{x_t\psi_t - u_t\theta_t}{x_t}\right) + L\theta_t\, dt
\end{align*}$$
which, when you try to apply integration by parts, yields the following EL equations
$$\begin{align*}E^x(L) &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}x_t - \frac{d}{dt}\left[L - \frac{u_t}{x_t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{u_t}{x_t}}\right]\\
E^u(L)&= \frac{\partial L}{\partial u}x_t - \frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{u_t}{x_t}}\right]\end{align*}$$
from the equation
$$\int_a^b E^x(L)\theta + E^u(L)\psi + \frac{d}{dt}\left[\left(L - \frac{u_t}{x_t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{u_t}{x_t}}\right)\theta + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{u_t}{x_t}}\psi\right]\,dt.$$
Now, we could just repeat this computation for the EL equations in the second-order case, but that gets pretty nasty considering the quotient rules and makes it difficult to generalize completely, so I was wondering if anyone knows of a better way to go about this computation. My first thought was to try to use Noether's Theorem for multiple dependent variables, but when I try to do that I do not seem to get the same equations out. If anyone can shed some light on where I've gone wrong or provide a general formula, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

**Update:** If it is helpful to anyone, here are the EL equations for the second and third-order cases.

For the second-order:
$$\begin{align*}E^x(L) &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} x_t - \frac{d}{dt}\left[ L - \frac{u_t}{x_t}D_3(L) + \frac{-2u_{tt}x_t + 3u_tx_{tt}}{x_t^3} D_4(L)\right] + \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left[\frac{-u_t}{x_t^2}D_4(L)\right]\\
E^u(L)&= \frac{\partial L}{\partial u}x_t - \frac{d}{dt}\left[D_3(L) - \frac{x_{tt}}{x_t^2}D_4(L)\right] + \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left[\frac{1}{x_t}D_4(L)\right]\end{align*}$$

For the third-order:
$${\scriptsize \begin{align*}E^x(L) &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} x_t - \frac{d}{dt}\left[ L - \frac{u_t}{x_t}D_3(L) + \frac{-2u_{tt}x_t + 3u_tx_{tt}}{x_t^3} D_4(L) + \frac{4u_t x_{ttt} x_t^5 - 15u_tx_{tt}^2x_t^4 + 12u_{tt}x_{tt}x_{t}^5 - 3u_{ttt}x_{t}^6}{x_t^9}D_5(L)\right] + \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left[\frac{-u_t}{x_t^2}D_4(L) + \frac{-3u_{tt}x_{t} + 6u_tx_{tt}}{x_t^4}D_5(L)\right] - \frac{d^3}{dt^3}\left[\frac{-u_t}{x_t^3}D_5(L)\right]\\
E^u(L)&= \frac{\partial L}{\partial u}x_t - \frac{d}{dt}\left[D_3(L) - \frac{x_{tt}}{x_t^2}D_4(L) + \frac{-x_t^6x_{ttt} + 3x_{t}^5x_{tt}^2}{x_{t}^9}D_5(L)\right] + \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left[\frac{1}{x_t}D_4(L)+\frac{-3x_t^6x_{tt}}{x_t^9}D_5(L)\right] - \frac{d^3}{dt^3}\left[\frac{1}{x_t^2}D_5(L)\right]\end{align*}}$$

Where $D_i(L)$ indicates taking the derivative with respect to the $i$-th coordinate of $L$.

Comment: For applying the EL formalism the conditions have to be match. Look at [Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for example. The `u_{t}` and `x_{t}` need to be independent ans already velocities or generalzied velocities. The special functional dependence in not of interest in the abstracted Lagrangian. There is an extended formalism with Lagrangian multiplies to paid attention to constraints: [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).